# How to insert variable number of spaces necessary to align textual columns in Vim?

Tags: vim, text, formatting

I’m a fan of Visual mode in Vim, as it allows to insert text before any given column.

For example, insertion of spaces after the quotation leaders below:

```
> one
> two
> three
```

can be done via `<Ctrl-V>jjI  <Esc>`:

```
>   one
>   two
>   three
```

as follows:

1. Start Visual mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>.
2. Extend visual selection with `jj`.
3. Insert some spaces with `I__`.
4. Propagate the change to all the lines of the block selection with <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Now I have a text file that needs some formatting. This is what it looks like:

```
start() -- xxx
initialize() -- xxx
go() -- xxx
```

Now I want to align part of this text to arrange it into columns like this:

```
start()       -- xxx
initialize()  -- xxx
go()          -- xxx
```

The problem I have is that I cannot insert a different amount of indentation into each line and merely indenting a fixed amount of spaces/tabs is insufficient.
How can you do an indentation where all indented text will have to be aligned at the same column?

#### Update

I only figured out a rather verbose and unwieldy method:

1. Find the string position to indent from: `\--`.
2. Insert n (let's say 20) spaces before that: `20i <Esc>`.
3. Delete a part of those spaces back to a certain column (let's say 15): `d|15`.
4. Save those steps as a macro and repeat the macro as often as necessary.

But this approach is very ugly, though!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert spaces up to column X to line up things in columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154306/how-to-insert-spaces-up-to-column-x-to-line-up-things-in-columns)

Comment: Your macro isn't that ugly. Ok, it's a few steps but that macro feature replaces a hundred different plugins, and it's only a few steps! Just bear in mind too, that if you start the macro with a search to the next position, and end the macro by calling itself, you can invoke the macro once and it will spin through the entire text doing its work and then fail at the end when it can't find another match.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm much better off without any vim plugins.
Here is my solution:

`<Shift-V>jj:!column -ts --`

Then insert `--` into multiple lines just as you wrote in the question.

---

You can also append a number of comments at insertion time.

`:set virtualedit=all`

`<Ctrl-V>jjA-- xxx<Esc>`

Comment: This is of course the way you should do it at insertion time. +1.

Comment: will not work in my case...the `--- xxx` parts on each line start at different columns. So you cannot align the edit parts of your visual selection. (the file I need to edit has already this structure and I need to re-format it accordingly)

Comment: Do you work on *nix?  If so, you can try `column` command within Vim.  `<Shift-V>jj:!column -ts --`, then insert `--` into multiple lines you want.

Comment: Yes I work on Linux/MacOS. I didn't know about the column command, nice one! works like a charm!

Comment: @ernix: I ended up using the solution you suggested in the comment. Could you update your answer with this so I can accept it?

Comment: I left my previous answer for comments above.  #FIXME: my broken English;)

Comment: setting
:set virtualedit=all and using <Shift-V>jj:!column -t inserts ^M markers if the first selected line is shorter than the second. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @YordanGrigorov Could you provide an example? I didn't quite get what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use a specific plugin, you can use either [Tabular](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/) or [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin in this case.

They both allow you to align text on specific characters, like `--` in your example. Their syntax is a bit different though. Pick the one that suit you the most.

Comment: just installed Tabular and it works correct. Nice...even though I was hoping that this rather small task would not involve installing a plugin. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @oliver:  It is possible to solve this task without the need to install a plugin.  The solution is not as compact as when using one of those plugins, though.

Answer (score 3):

Without plugin and if you have already entered your comments without emix's solution:

```
:,+2 s/--/                                    &
```

This will ensure all comments are to be shifted leftwise in order to align them properly.

Then blockwise select the column to which you want to align the text, and : `100<`

Comment: Also, consider `:,2s/\ze--/\=repeat(' ',32)`.

Comment: @ib.: this is also good, but depending on your keyboard settings, can be slower to type!

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to align text in columns is to use the [Tabular](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3464) or
[Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin. If neither of these is ready at hand, one can use
the following somewhat tricky (and a little cumbersome looking) yet
perfectly working (for the case in question) commands.<sup>1,2</sup>

```
:let m=0|g/\ze -- /let m=max([m,searchpos(@/,'c')[1]])
:%s//\=repeat(' ',m-col('.'))
```

The purpose of the first command is to determine the width of the
column to the left of the separator (which I assume to be `--`
here). The width is calculated as a maximum of the lengths of the text
in the first column among all the lines. The `:global` command is used
to enumerate the lines containing the separator (the other lines do
not require aligning). The `\ze` atom located just after the beginning
of the pattern, sets the end of the match at the same position where
it starts (see `:help \ze`). Changing the borders of the match does
not affect the way `:global` command works, the pattern is written in
such a manner just to match the needs of the next substitution
command: Since these two commands could share the same pattern, it can
be omitted in the second one.

The command that is run on the matched lines,

```
:let m=max([m,searchpos(@/,'c')[1]])
```

calls the `searchpos()` function to search for the pattern used in the
parent `:global` command, and to get the column position of the match.
The pattern is referred to as `@/` using the last search pattern
register (see `:help "/`). This takes advantage of the fact that the
`:global` command updates the `/` register as soon as it starts
executing. The `c` flag passed as the second argument in the
`searchpos()` call allows the match at the first character of a line
(`:global` positions the cursor at the very beginning of the line to
execute a command on), because it could be that there is no text to
the left of the separator. The `searchpos()` function returns a list,
the first element of which is the line number of the matched position,
and the second one is the column position. If the command is run on
a line, the line matches the pattern of the containing `:global`
command. As `searchpos()` is to look for the same pattern, there is
definitely a match on that line. Therefore, only the column starting
the match is in interest, so it gets extracted from the returning list
by the `[1]` subscript. This very position equals to the width of the
text in the first column of the line, plus one. Hence, the `m` variable
is set to the maximum of its current value and that column position.

The second command,

```
:%s//\=repeat(' ',m-col('.'))
```

pads the first occurrence of the separator on all of the lines that
contain it, with the number of spaces that is missing to make the text
before the separator to take `m` characters, minus one. This command
is a global substitution replacing an empty interval just before the
separator (see the comment about the `:global` command above) with the
result of evaluation of the expression (see `:help sub-replace-\=`)

```
repeat(' ',m-col('.'))
```

The `repeat()` function repeats its first argument (as string) the
number of times given in the second argument. Since on every
substitution the cursor is moved to the start of the pattern match,
`m-col('.')` equals exactly to the number of spaces needed to shift
the separator to the right to align columns (`col('.')` returns the
current column position of the cursor).

---

<sup>1</sup> Below is a one-line version of this pair of commands.

```
:let m=0|exe'g/\ze -- /let m=max([m,searchpos(@/,"c")[1]])'|%s//\=repeat(' ',m-col('.'))
```

<sup>2</sup> In previous revisions of the answer the commands used
to be as follows.

```
:let p=[0]|%s/^\ze\(.*\) -- /\=map(p,'max([v:val,len(submatch(1))+1])')[1:0]/
:exe'%s/\ze\%<'.p[0].'c -- /\=repeat(" ",'.p[0].'-col("."))'
```

Those who are interested in these particular commands can find their
detailed description in this answer’s edit history.

Comment: wow...looks kind of involved! would you care to explain your solution?

Comment: @oliver:  Sure.  I have added a detailed explanation to the answer.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! although I don't think I would use this (I could NEVER remember :) in practice I really enjoyed reading along your answer and for sure learned some things about vim ... again!

Comment: @oliver:  That's OK.  Actually, I come up with such tricky commands as a result of extensive experimentation which leads myself to learning something new about Vim.  So, I doubly glad if an outcome of my learning process helps others.  (By the way, I've found a simpler pair of commands to do the same.  See the rewritten answer.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification on Benoit's answer that has two steps.

First step, block select text search and replace -- with lots of spaces.

```
'<,'>s/--/                         --/
```

Now all the comments should have lots of spaces, but still be uneven.

Second step,  block select the text again and use another regex to match all the characters you want to keep (say the first 20 characters or so) plus all the spaces following, and to replace it with a copy of those first 20 characters:

```
'<,'>s/\(.\{20}\)\s*/\1/
```

Not quite as easy as Benoit's, but I couldn't figure out how to make his second step work.