# How to do something in a function based on the character under the cursor in Vim?

Tags: vim, text-cursor

I’m writing a function that edits a certain environment in LaTeX.

The environment basically looks like this:

```
\begin{quicktikz}
    ...some stuff...
\end{quicktikz}
```

or like this:

```
\begin*{quicktikz}
    ...some stuff...
\end{quicktikz}
```

I want to write a function that toggles between the two, when called from within the environment. Since my Vim knowledge ain’t all that, I’m coming up with a simple solution:

1. Get cursor position with `let save_cursor=getpos(".")`.
2. Backward search for `\begin{quicktikz}` using: `?\\begin{quicktikz}\|\\begin\*{quicktikz}`.
3. Search for the `{` and move left using: `normal 0f{h`.
4. Check if the item under cursor equals `*`:

   - if it does, do `normal x`;
   - if it doesn’t, do `normal a*<esc>`.
5. Restore cursor position using  `call setpos('.',save_cursor)`.

I know how to do all of this except for step 3. How can I check if the char under the cursor equals to `*` or not?

If you know a better way of doing this, sharing this would be welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the easiest way to retrieve the char under cursor is:

```
getline(".")[col(".")-1]
```

Alternatively, you can do it with `strpart()`

```
strpart(getline("."), col(".")-1, 1)
```

---

The first expression first calls the function [`getline()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#getline()) passing `"."` as
argument which means the line where the cursor is positioned will be returned.
Then we use the so called *expr8* or *expr-[]* (see the [help](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr8)) to retrieve a
single character. The number passed comes from another function, [`col()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#col())
which returns the current cursor column. As indexes start in 0, one is subtracted.

You can use it like

```
if getline(".")[col(".")-1] == '*'
        ...
```

Comment: Also, could you give some explanation to each part of the syntax? I'm trying to learn vim!

Comment: Sorry @romeovs, I just edited the answer. The second expression is easy enough to decipher with a little :h :-) but let me know if you have any questions on it.

Comment: @sidyll:  Interesting use of `strpart()` function!  By the way, do you know an easy way to extract a character by its index (in characters, not byte index) from Unicode string?  Something like `substitute(s, '^.\{7}\(.\).*$', '\1', '')`?

Comment: @sidyll:  Regarding a better way, I have had a go for approaching not the issue of getting the character under the cursor, but the problem as a whole.  As a result I have run into an interesting combination of Vim features converging on the problem.

Comment: @ib. (sorry for the delay in replying, I was in another city far from computer for a moment :-) The help for `expr8` indeed says it won't work with multi-byte strings, but points to another useful function called `byteidx()`. Take a look in these two, this function might be the solution.

Comment: @sidyll:  `:h byteidx()` provides an example solving just that problem.  Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Yep `byteidx` works well. Here's an example mapping I use to search for the "current character": `nnoremap <expr> ! '/' . matchstr(getline('.'), '.', byteidx(getline('.'), col('.') - 1))`.

Answer (score 3):

Let me propose an alternative implementation of the technique you describe.

```
:?\\begin\>\zs\*\=?s//\='*'[submatch(0)!='']/|norm!``
```

The above command consists of two separate commands chained with `|` (see
`:help :bar`) in one line.  The first one is a substitution (see `:help :s`)
performed for each line in the specified range,

```
?\\begin\>\zs\*\=?
```

According to the range syntax (see `:help :range`), this range specifies the
only line, that is the previous line where the `\\begin\>\zs\*\=` pattern
matches the word `begin` preceded with a backslash and followed by by optional
star character.<sup>1</sup>  The `\zs` atom between parts of the pattern
matching `\begin` and `*`, sets the start of the match there.  So, the match
of the whole pattern is either empty or contains single star character.  This
is not necessary for specifying a line in the range, it is useful for reusing
the same pattern later in the `:substitute` command, where only that star
character or its empty place should be replaced.  For details about the
pattern's syntax see `:help /\>`, `:help /\=`, `:help /\zs`.

The substitution itself,

```
s//\='*'[submatch(0)!='']/
```

replaces the first occurrence of the last search pattern (which is set by the
backward search in the range) with a string to which the expression
`'*'[submatch(0)!='']` evaluates (see `:help sub-replace-\=`).  As the pattern
matches only an empty string or a star character, the subexpression
`submatch(0)!=''` evaluates to zero if there is no star after `\begin`, or to
one otherwise.  Zero subscript from the string `'*'` results in a substring
containing the first character of that one-character string.  Index one is
equal to the length of the string, therefore subscript results in an empty
string.  Thus, when there is a star after `\begin`, it gets replaced with an
empty string, when a star is not present, zero-width interval just after
`\begin` is substituted with `*`.

The second command,

```
:norm!``
```

takes advantage of the fact that `:substitute` command stores the current
cursor position before it actually starts replacement.  The ``` `` ``` movement
command jumps back to the position before the latest jump (which occurs in the
aforementioned substitution command) restoring position of the
cursor.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>  Be careful with search, since in ranges, as usual, it wraps
around the end of file, when the `wrapscan` option is enabled (it is turned on
by default).

<sup>2</sup>  Do not confuse ``` `` ``` with the `''` command which moves the
cursor to the first non-blank character in the line of the location before the
latest jump.

Comment: `submatch(0)=="*"?"":"*"` is only longer by two characters, but +1 for the idea. Still, why use `:exe`?

Comment: @Benoit:  Actually, I have shortened that substitute-with-an-expression part by one more character. :-)  Anyway, you are right, that expression is reasonable, too.

Comment: @Benoit:  Usage of `:exe` in the command from previous revisions of the answer was caused by the need to restore exact cursor location after executing the `:global` command.  Without `:exe` the cursor jumped to the first non-blank character of the line of its previous location, not to the actual column position.  It turned out that that `:global` command was redundant, without it, the `:exe` call is no longer needed.

Comment: I see that you like golf and I enjoy deciphering your new findings. This one is far more readable and even shorter than the previous one, I would add another +1 if that was possible.

Comment: @Benoit:  By the way, similarly, today I found an [improvement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529029/inserting-indentation-for-columns-in-vim/7538363#7538363) lightening the solution for another recent question, "[Inserting indentation for columns in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529029/inserting-indentation-for-columns-in-vim)".  It could be interesting to see how over-complicated the first approach to problem can be.